# floor giving different results on different platforms

Tags: c++, linux, macos

I am trying to implement a system in C++ where I can tell if a number is whole (everything after decimal is zero). For this I was using `if (sqrt(answer / 2) == floor(sqrt(answer / 2)))`

My problem is that I am getting different results on different systems, macOS and Linux Fedora 27. On my Linux machine I am running GCC 7.3.1 20180130 and the macOS machines are at my school and I am not able to check them right now. I am aware that macOS uses ridiculously old versions of open source tools though.

My whole code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  double answer = 1.0;
  loop:
// uncomment line under for verbose
  cout << "testing " << answer << endl;
  if (sqrt(answer / 2) != floor(sqrt(answer / 2))) {
    answer++;
    goto loop;
  } else { if (cbrt(answer / 3) == floor(cbrt(answer / 3))) {
      cout << "ANSWER IS " << answer << endl;
      return 0;
    } else {
      answer++;
      goto loop;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have complied a list of a few I/O pairs:

output of `cbrt(answer / 3.0)` when `answer` is `648.0` is `6`

output of `floor(cbrt(answer / 3.0))` when `answer` is `648.0` is `6`

`(cbrt(answer / 3.0) == floor(cbrt(answer / 3.0)))` is false

`(cbrt(648.0 / 3.0) == floor(cbrt(648.0 / 3.0)))` is true

I know that this is probably a floating point issue, and I don't know if there is a better way to check if a number is a whole number.

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Why cant you just do `if(fabs(answer - static_cast<int>(answer)) < THRESHOLD)` to tell whether or not your number is whole(ish)?

Comment: Assume `10.0/2.0==4.99999999`; then `std::floor(10.0/2.0)==4.0`

Comment: @scohe001 thanks that seems to work. I ended up using `if ((fabs(cbrt(answer / 3.0) - static_cast<int>(cbrt(answer / 3.0)))) < 0.000000001)`. Thats good enough ^TM for me.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thats what I was thinking, I guess the precision of the `cout` clause I was using rounded it.

Comment: I still don't understand the deal with the different platforms returning different booleans, though

Answer (score 0):

sqrt() and cbrt() don't have to come into this. By the normal mathematical definition of "whole number", all you need to know is whether the fractional part is zero. It should be enough to check:

if ( floor( answer ) == answer ) ...

The reason why you're getting mismatches here probably has little to do with the sqrt() or cbrt(). It's more about dividing by 3.0. In base 10, when you divide by 3, you get a repeating decimal, e.g.:

1.0 / 3.0 = 0.3333333...

A floating point number--even a double--can only hold so much precision. Even if you multiply what you have above back by 3.0, it might be off by a little bit:

(1.0 / 3.0) * 3.0 = 0.9999999...

Some computers implement "divide by 3.0" as "multiply by one-third" internally. They can be off by a single bit in the last digit, but that's enough to change the 1.0 to 0.9999... Those numbers will produce different results when you floor() them.

The sqrt() and cbrt() functions could have similar off by 1 in the last digit issues.

One way to avoid this is to say, "Well, I just want something that's *close* to a whole number." Then you just decide how close is good enough, and test for that instead:

if ( abs( round( answer ) - answer ) < .0001 ) ...

These details of machine arithmetic can get complicated, very quickly. Different machines may have different answers in the last digit under different conditions. Something like the line above is probably the best solution unless and until you're ready for the complicated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the different systems have different levels of precision on their float values, so (for example) one may end up with `XX.9999997` while the other gets `XX.00000020`. This is a big reason **not** to use `ceil` or `floor`. Instead, if you need to round just use `round`.

In this situation, you can use `fabs` (floating point absolute value) to make sure you're under some threshold:

```
if(fabs(answer - static_cast<int>(answer)) < THRESHOLD) {
    std::cout << "We're whole!";
}
```